# Can you navigate other websites from your page using an iframe?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a webpage from which I can browse my social media feeds, email inbox and news sources through iframes. Is this at all possible? I have noticed that youtube and facebook for instance do not allow their sites to be displayed in an iframe. Are there any alternatives to make this work?

Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: I would say *the browser* already is such a (i)frame through which you can do all those things…

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using iFrames; there are lots of issues with them. There are widgets released by the companies listed that provide you a with a news feed style block that you place on your website.

Comment: You can use your facebook page iframe and your youtube video iframe into your site.

Answer (score 1):

If a simple  isn't working then there isn't any way of doing it in Javascript either. The most likely reason for the iframe not working is because the target site is sending a header to prevent other sites iframing it:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

A lot of sites will do this to prevent a common vulnerability known as UI Redressing or Click Hijacking. Some sites will also include some frame busting Javascript as a backup security measure to the HTTP header.

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a  or . Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.